# Smoothly "Audialize" Recursion in Python with Turtle and PyAudio

Tags: python, audio, recursion

I'd like to be able to reproduce the idea behind the code below, but with sound that is not horribly harsh to listen to. Ideally I'd like a solution that uses code that school kids can understand (the play_note function can be imported so they don't have to worry about how that works). One answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075923/3042018) suggested the clicking between consecutive notes is due to incomplete cycles of sound , but I don't know how to fix that for changing durations.

Can anyone help with this please? Can it be made to work with some tweaking or is the approach flawed somehow?

```
import turtle
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

def play_note(freq, dur):

  p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

  volume = 0.5     # range [0.0, 1.0]
  fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
  duration = dur   # in seconds, may be float
  f = freq       # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

  # generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
  samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

  # for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
  stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                  channels=1,
                  rate=fs,
                  output=True)

  # play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively) 
  stream.write(volume*samples)

  stream.stop_stream()
  stream.close()

  p.terminate()

def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 5:
        freq = branchLen * 2 + 400
        dur = branchLen / 100.0
        print freq, dur
        play_note(freq, dur)
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(20)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.left(40)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branchLen)

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.speed(0)
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.backward(100)
    t.down()
    t.color("green")
    tree(75,t)
    myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

Comment: Clicking occurs in audio when the amplitude changes suddenly, which can happen if you cut off your sine wave in the middle of a cycle. The solution is to add an envelope, which in your case just means fading out the last, say, 10-20ms of samples.

Comment: Thanks @Linuxios. Any chance you could let me know how to modify my code to achieve that?

Comment: I posted an answer that should be a reasonable starting point, let me know if there's anything in it I can expand on or explain more.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what do you need. I tried to run your code. It ran into some issues. So I fixed it. Then brought together all the variables for easy accessibility. Modified functions for the variables so that they can be set from main function. imported needed modules.

I've provided `freq` and `duration` outside of recursion. Hence they are fixed. In original code, `freq` increases and duration decreases with respect to tree length. That's one of the reason for noise as the `freq` and `duration` are then not multiples of 60 seconds and hence creates gap that leads to noise. With fixed `freq` and `duration`, the noise is minimum.

There will be some noise due to microseconds delay in creating new branch and for recursion to kick in.
Here is **EDITED** code.

```
import pyaudio
import turtle
import numpy as np

def play_note(freq, dur):

  p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

  volume = 0.5     # range [0.0, 1.0]
  fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
  duration = dur   # in seconds, may be float
  f = freq       # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

  # generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
  samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

  # for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
  stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                  channels=1,
                  rate=fs,
                  output=True)

  # play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively) 
  stream.write(volume*samples)

  stream.stop_stream()
  stream.close()

  p.terminate()

def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 5:

        freq = branchLen * 2 + 420
        dur = branchLen / 60.0
        print "branchLen={} , Freq = {}, Duration={}".format(branchLen, freq, dur)
        t.forward(branchLen)
        play_note(freq, dur)
        t.right(20)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        play_note(freq, dur)
        t.left(40)
        play_note(freq, dur)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        play_note(freq, dur)
        t.right(20)
        play_note(freq, dur)
        t.backward(branchLen)
        play_note(freq, dur)


def main():  
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.speed(turtle_speed)
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(branch_left_turn)
    t.up()
    t.backward(branch_back_turn)
    t.down()
    t.color(tree_color)
    tree(tree_length,t)
    myWin.exitonclick()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Global Variables brought together for easy setting
    turtle_speed = 0.5  #speed of turtle graphics <1 -> faster ; >1 -> slower 
    tree_length = 60    #keep within multiples of 60 for smoothness
    branch_left_turn = 90
    branch_back_turn = 100
    tree_color = "green" #can experiment with "red" "blue" etc
    #Call main function
    main()
```

Output Data:

```
  Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
branchLen=60 , Freq = 540, Duration=1.0
branchLen=45 , Freq = 510, Duration=0.75
branchLen=30 , Freq = 480, Duration=0.5
branchLen=15 , Freq = 450, Duration=0.25
branchLen=15 , Freq = 450, Duration=0.25
branchLen=30 , Freq = 480, Duration=0.5
branchLen=15 , Freq = 450, Duration=0.25
branchLen=15 , Freq = 450, Duration=0.25
branchLen=45 , Freq = 510, Duration=0.75
branchLen=30 , Freq = 480, Duration=0.5
branchLen=15 , Freq = 450, Duration=0.25
branchLen=15 , Freq = 450, Duration=0.25
branchLen=30 , Freq = 480, Duration=0.5
branchLen=15 , Freq = 450, Duration=0.25
branchLen=15 , Freq = 450, Duration=0.25
>>>
```

Output Image
[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying. I want the pitch and/or duration to vary with the branch length though, in order to experiment with different ways of representing the program acoustically. Shorter branches should have shorter duration. Even with your solution there is an ugly cut off to each note. Is there a way to smooth the end of each note?

Comment: I believe to truly get rid of clicks you will need to look into advanced techniques like fourier transform. However, just by observation, I noticed that the clicks are when the turtle arrow retracts backward . since we just had `play_note` for forward movement. I added `play_note` for other movements as well and that seems to have reduced the clicks. You may infact give different `freq` to different direction movement to reconize this way. I also fixed the old code to give original varying `freq` and modified my response. Hope this helps further.

Answer (score 1):

Clicks occur in audio when the amplitude changes suddenly, for example when a sine wave is interrupted near the peak of one of its cycles. The solution to this is to smoothly fade out (and possibly in) the sine wave. Generally, when synthesizing sound, these volume changes are called the sound's *envelope*.

A simple (but probably not very efficient) envelope for your code could look like this:

```
def play_note(freq, dur):

  p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

  volume = 0.5     # range [0.0, 1.0]
  fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
  duration = dur   # in seconds, may be float
  f = freq       # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

  # generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
  samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

  #Fade out the end
  release_time = 0.020 #(seconds)
  release_samples = np.ceil(release_time * fs)
  fade_curve = np.linspace(1.0, 0.0, num=release_samples)
  samples[-release_samples:] *= fade_curve
```

This could be tweaked by changing the release time or using a different fade curve. It could also be extended to apply an [ADSR](https://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/glossary_envelope.htm) envelope to the whole note.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work - the amplitude of the sound doesn't change over time as far as I can tell. Am I missing something? I made `release_samples` into an int to avoid an error, and tried different release times. Not sure what I can change re `fade-curve` but the clicks are still there. Any more help you can give please?