# Smooth Audio with PyAudio

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I am trying do some sound experiments with Python and I need a decent implementation of a `play_tone(freq, dur)` function. I have looked far and wide over a long period of time and have so far found three implementations, only one of which approaches the basic smoothness of sound that I require when playing rapid sequences of notes.

I have not studied the maths/physics of sound generation so am taking a lot of the code on trust - once I know why the best one of these approaches works best, I will use that as a staring point to study further.

So I'm looking for an explanation of why the two "worst" version have so much clipping and clicking while the best version (which uses `struct`) is so much smoother. I expect [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075923/3042018) has something to do with it, but I'm not sure how.

Also, I would love to find a way to make the last note of the smoothest version not click on the last note - i.e I want it to end smoothly.

```
# This is the smoothest version I can find

import math
import struct
import pyaudio

def play_tone(frequency, duration, stream, amplitude=0.5, fs=44100):
    N = int(fs / frequency)
    T = int(frequency * duration)  # repeat for T cycles
    dt = 1.0 / fs
    # 1 cycle
    tone = (amplitude * math.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * n * dt)
            for n in range(N))
    # Notice the b to transform the operation in a bytes operation
    data = b''.join(struct.pack('f', samp) for samp in tone)
    for n in range(T):
        stream.write(data)

#Usage
fs = 48000
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
    channels=1,
    rate=fs,
    output=True)
a = 2 ** (1 / 24)
f0 = 110
qts = [f0 * a ** p for p in range(96)]
for i in range(0, len(qts) - 24, 3):
    for j in range(i, i + 24, 4):
        play_tone(qts[j], 0.1, stream)

stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

---

```
# This is the second smoothest version I can find

import math
import numpy
import pyaudio

def sine(frequency, length, rate):
    length = int(length * rate)
    factor = float(frequency) * (math.pi * 2) / rate
    return numpy.sin(numpy.arange(length) * factor)


def play_tone(stream, frequency=440, length=1, rate=44100):
    chunks = []
    chunks.append(sine(frequency, length, rate))

    chunk = numpy.concatenate(chunks) * 0.25

    stream.write(chunk.astype(numpy.float32).tostring())

#Usage
fs = 48000
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
    channels=1,
    rate=fs,
    output=True)
a = 2 ** (1 / 24)
f0 = 110
qts = [f0 * a ** p for p in range(96)]
for i in range(0, len(qts) - 24, 3):
    for j in range(i, i + 24, 4):
        play_tone(stream, qts[j], 0.1)

stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

---

```
# This is the least smooth version I can find

import numpy as np
import pyaudio

def play_tone(freq, dur, stream, fs=44100):

  volume = 0.5     # range [0.0, 1.0]
  duration = dur   # in seconds, may be float
  f = freq       # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

  # generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
  samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

  # play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively)
  stream.write(volume*samples)

#Usage
fs = 48000
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
    channels=1,
    rate=fs,
    output=True)
a = 2 ** (1 / 24)
f0 = 110
qts = [f0 * a ** p for p in range(96)]
for i in range(0, len(qts) - 24, 3):
    for j in range(i, i + 24, 4):
        play_tone(qts[j], 0.5, stream)

stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your waveform generator so that the amplitude starts at zero, ramps up to the desired value over a certain time period (say 1/10 of the total duration), and ramps down to zero over the same period at the end.

That way, the signal is *always* zero at the end and the beginning of each tone, *no matter the frequency or phase*. That should yield smooth transitions everywhere.

Comment: I don't suppose you could provide a simple script that defines a `play_tone(freq, dur)` function which does that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an experienced programmer (also more used to javascript). Also, this is an old question, but I didn't find a good answer anywhere. So I had a shot at this.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import math

def play_tone(frequency, dur):
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    volume = 0.8     # range [0.0, 1.0]
    fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
#   duration = 0.3   # in seconds, may be float
    duration=dur    #"dur" parameter can be removed and set directly
    f=frequency

    # We need to ramp up (I used an exponential growth formula)
    # from low volume to the volume we want.
    # For some reason (I can't bothered to figure that out) the
    # following factor is needed to calculate how many steps are
    # needed to reach maximum volume:
    # 0.693147 = -LN(0.5)

    stepstomax = 50
    stepstomax_mod = int(round(stepstomax/0.693147)) 
    ramprate  = 1/(math.exp(0.5)*stepstomax_mod)

    decayrate = 0.9996
    #Decay could be programmed better. It doesn't take tone duration into account.
    #That means it might not reach an inaudible level before the tone ends. 

    #sine wave
    samples1=(np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(0,fs*duration,1)*f/fs))

    stepcounter=0
    for nums in samples1:
        thisnum=samples1[stepcounter]
        if stepcounter<stepstomax_mod:
            #the ramp up stage
            samples1[stepcounter]=volume*thisnum*(pow(ramprate+1,stepcounter+1)-1)
        else:
            #the decay stage
            samples1[stepcounter]=volume*thisnum*(pow(decayrate,stepcounter-stepstomax)) 
        stepcounter+=1

    samples = samples1.astype(np.float32).tobytes()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
        channels=1,
        rate=fs,
        output=True)        
    stream.write(samples)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

play_tone(261.6, 0.3)
play_tone(329.6, 0.3)
play_tone(392, 0.3) 
play_tone(523.3, 0.6)
```

I was programming something similar in javascript and there is a [very good article](http://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/) on pretty much the same problem in webaudio (getting rid of the click; making a nice sound). What I tried to do was to translate the click removal at the beginning of a note from webaudio/javascript to python.